# Make Javascript Trigger 2 Buttons On Keypress

Tags: javascript, html

I have been wanting Javascript to trigger a button that will save the values from several textboxes and trigger a reset button for another element to load the values after the **enter** key is pressed. I know that the 2 buttons work correctly but the Javascript code I have for the key press trigger doesn't.

**Example:**

Let's say I have this Javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("savevalues")
.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById("reset").click();
}
});
```

And let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="savevalues()" id="savevalues">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="reset()" id="reset">Button 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? If you need to see the Javascript and HTML code, here is a link to my github project: https://github.com/jamesestes1711/2048-hacked
The Javascript file is located in the js folder and is named: game_manager.js and the keypress code is at the bottom of the file. The HTML code is located in the home folder and is called: play.html.

**EDIT**

I have tried changing .click() to reset() and still no change.

Comment: Replace `document.getElementById("restart").click();` with `restart();` or whatever function it triggers.

Comment: you are binding keyup event listener to a button, how and when it will gonna call??

Comment: I have fixed the reset in the HTML and still does the same thing

Comment: @Durga It's a bit awkward, but when the button has focus, as it does after click, key presses will trigger key events on the button

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this code:

```
document.getElementById("restart").click();
```

To

```
document.getElementById("reset").click();
```

so that the JS matches the HTML element

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted here should work apart from the fact that you use "reset" as ID and try to reference it with "restart".

I took a peek at your project and there you correctly use "restart" for both. However, in your game_manager.js, you're trying to reference the element with ID "savevalues" with `document.getElementById("applyvalues")`.

That's your problem right there.

Comment: I was just making an example @Mikael

Comment: @user7986429 As I said, I looked at the code in your actual project. play.html contains `<button id="savevalues" ...` while game_manager.js has `document.getElementById("applyvalues")`

Comment: I fixed the error and still no change. When I was uploading the files I made a few modifications to play.html and game_manager.js and I forgot what I put in play.html and didn't realize it so that is probably why it said that @Mikael . My original code does match up though so I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: It should work, assuming your "restart" button actually has an event listener for the `click` event. I can't see that you actually add such an event listener anywhere in your code. Add a `console.log("Trigger restart");` in your `if (event.keyCode == 13) { }` block to verify that it never triggers the click event (or that it actually does).

Comment: Don't tell me it doesn't work, tell me what happens after you added the `console.log`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined